# Propagating type definitions on child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component defined as follows:

```
// Form.Container.tsx

export default function MyForm(props: IFormProps): JSX.Element {
  /*
    some crazy logic here
  */
  return (
    <Form<{initialValues: RFFFormProps['initialValues'] }> initialValues={{ name: 'John Doe' }}>
      <FormField type="text" name="name" />
      {/* more FormField components here */}
    </Form>

  )
}
```

I'm fairly new with Typescript but I've been able to get a hold on the concepts since I have some background on C#. I am trying to propagate the types through the child components. What I mean is that I want to be able to make **FormField** props values to be enforced depending on what **Form**.*initialValues* prop receives. For example, I want **FormField**.*name* to only accept the key values that **Form**.*initialValues* receives (in this case, **name** can only receive a value of "name" since it's the only key in **initialValues**). Is there a way to do that or is it something that Typescript doesn't allow?

Comment: I don't think this is possible right now